# Track how often link was clicked

Tags: tracking

I am currently running a website where I promote different coffees from pubs in my city. On my website I have links to the different coffees.

I have recently seen some of this links being shared on Facebook and other social networks.

So I was wondering if it is somehow possible to track how often one of this links are being clicked?

I have tried using redirects to my site but Facebook uses my pictures in the previews, whereas I don't want this because it is misleading.

I have seen that this works with Bitly so it must somehow be possible?
And there are of course different services providing this, but it would be nice if it would run without any foreign services.

So basically I am looking for a solution which will let me know how often a link, origination from my site was clicked in Facebook, Google+ or any other forum.

Answer (score 0):

There definitely is. Try looking into Google Analytics, it will show you show much data from your personal websites and links that it can blow your mind! [Here is the link](http://www.google.com/analytics/ce/nrs/?utm_expid=71218119-7.lBgmrTO8R3uEDwsxNxa_Nw.2&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F)

> Google Analytics helps you analyze visitor traffic and paint a
>   complete picture of your audience and their needs. Track the routes
>   people take to reach you and the devices they use to get there with
>   reporting tools like Traffic Sources. Learn what people are looking
>   for and what they like with In-Page Analytics. Then tailor your
>   marketing and site content for maximum impact.

You can even get a free package to use!
Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my post. I have came across google and co. but it would be nice if it could work without google or else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have plenty of analytical options.

Something as straight forward as Google Analytics for example.

If you are using cpanel on your hosts server, you even have options such as AWSTATS, which will also provide information.

If all else fails you can even use post data stored in your apache / nginx logs.

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my post. I have came across google and co. but it would be nice if it could work without google or else.

Comment: As I mentioned above, AWSTATS is a decent Idea if you are using a host that supports cpanel. Otherwise if you have access to server logs and you are checking referral links correctly, then you can often find out this information in such a manner, It's just a fair bit more work.

Comment: Ok. I will look this up. Thank you.

I have also came across the so called tracking pixel, but as far as i have understood this i can NOT use this in my case?

Comment: Tracking pixels can sometimes be used. one method of implementation for example. create the transparent tracking pixel, Place it on various sites or posts you would like to track. once someone views or loads the pixel, you will be notified upon request in your logs. it's rudimentary and works best when an application is created / used.

Comment: Ok. But I want to track a link when it is clicked. So that i can make sure that the user got the link form my page.

Comment: Then a tracking pixel will not be your solution. They are simply meant to inform you when someone has viewed a particular psot or email. mostly used strickly with email.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have amended your question you might want to check out [this](http://clickmeter.com/) tool. It is not google. :)

It is called Click Meter and performs Link Tracking and provides click reports, etc